# UIHostingController view pinned to a UIView is in the wrong position when a VStack updates

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `SwiftUI` view representing a panel of buttons:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Buttons: View {

    @State var isButton1Hidden = false
    @State var isButton2Hidden = true
    @State var isButton3Hidden = true

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if !isButton1Hidden {
                Button {
                    isButton2Hidden = false
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "triangle")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }

            if !isButton2Hidden {
                Button {
                    // Action
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                .clipShape(Circle())

            }

            if !isButton3Hidden {
                Button {
                    // Action
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "square")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                .background(.black.opacity(0.7))
                .clipShape(Circle())
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Buttons_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Buttons()
    }
}
```

This is added to a view controller view `UIHostingController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttons = Buttons()
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: buttons)

        addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)

        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let horizConstraint = hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,
            constant: -16.0
        )

        let vertConstraint = hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: view.topAnchor,
            constant: 16.0
        )

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizConstraint, vertConstraint])
    }

}
```

The result is as follows:

[image]

This is what I expect. The view is pinned correctly to the top of the `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. However if I change the state in the panel of buttons and hide/unhide (tap the first button) them the view is no longer in the correct position:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way to keep this panel aligned to the top?

Comment: It does not look like SwiftUI part related. Anyway needed MRE or access to project to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As you leave height constraint ambiguous UIHostingController specifies constant one for itself by initial root view height. I can recommend the following approach:

1. give it bottom constraint explicitly, like

   ```
    let vertConstraint1 = hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
        constant: 16.0
    )

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizConstraint, vertConstraint, vertConstraint1])
   ```
2. push buttons to top (because they are at center now, by default)

   ```
    VStack {
        Button() {}
        Button() {}
        Button() {}
        Spacer()     // << here !!
    }
   ```

**) by default hosting view background is not transparent, so

```
    hostingController.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.4

[image]

[Complete test module is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestHostingInViewController.swift)

Comment: I tried this thanks. No different though. And actually snapkit `snp.makeConstraints` sets `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` anyway.

I attached some screenshots of the view debug